# Shopify livereload grunt

Tags: gruntjs, shopify, livereload

Has anyone got `Shopify` `LiveReload` to work for their workflow development to work with `grunt`? Please bare in mind, when viewing a live preview of the development, it's not stored locally, but instead through shopify's custom url's.

If anyone knows how to get `livereload` to work on shopify, I would be more than thankful.

Thanks in advance.

My Gruntfile:

```
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // load all grunt tasks
    require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

    // configurable paths
    var yeomanConfig = {
        app: '.',
        dist: 'fahey-rodriguez4877-7509645'
    };

    grunt.initConfig({
        yeoman: yeomanConfig,
        watch: {
            compass: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['compass:live'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            css: {
                files: ['.tmp/styles/*.css'],
                tasks: ['cssmin'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            js: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/*.js'],
                tasks: ['concat:live'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            update: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/{layout,templates,snippets}/*.liquid'],
                tasks: ['sync'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            config: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/config/*.{html,json}'],
                tasks: ['copy']
            },
        },
        clean: {
            dist: [
                '.tmp',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*'
            ]
        },
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
            },
            all: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        },
        compass: {
            options: {
                sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
                imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/assets',
                javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/assets',
                importPath: 'components',
                relativeAssets: true
            },
            dist: {},
            live: {
                options: {
                    debugInfo: true,
                }
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/custom.modernizr.js': [
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>/components/foundation/js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js'
                    ],
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/main.js': [
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>/components/foundation/js/vendor/jquery.js',
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>/components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.js',
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>/components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.*.js',
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
                    ],
                }
            },
        },
        concat: {
            live: {
                files: {
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/custom.modernizr.js': [
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>/components/foundation/js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js'
                    ],
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/main.js': [
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>/components/foundation/js/vendor/jquery.js',
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>/components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.js',
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>/components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.*.js',
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
                    ],
                }
            }
        },
        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/assets',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets'
                }]
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/main.css': [
                        '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        sync: {
            main: {
                files: [{
                  cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                  src: [
                            'assets/*',
                            'config/*',
                            'layout/*',
                            'snippets/*',
                            'templates/*',
                        ],
                  dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                }]
            }
        },
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        'assets/*',
                        'config/*',
                        'layout/*',
                        'snippets/*',
                        'templates/*',
                    ]
                },{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/components/font-awesome/font',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets',
                    src: [
                        '*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
        }
    });

    grunt.renameTask('regarde', 'watch');

    grunt.registerTask('live', [
        'clean:dist',
        'compass:live',
        'cssmin',
        'concat:live',
        'copy',
        'watch'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'compass:dist',
        'cssmin',
        'imagemin',
        'uglify',
        'copy'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'jshint',
        'build'
    ]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey this would be awesome too as I use LiveReload for all my projects, but I think it's really for local web development servers rather than live servers, or in this case shopify which doesn't give you any kind of server level control in that respect.

However, there is this awesome [grunt task](https://github.com/wilr/grunt-shopify)!

it essentially watches any file changes when editing files locally, then automatically uploads them to the respective shopify store/theme, I've not had any issues with it at all and it's been a huge timesaver.

Hope that helps :)